# ClassCastException: com.example.test.MyView can not be cast to com.example.test.MyView at

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

As the title shows, I have encountered such a problem. I'm pretty sure my xml layout is correct and it should work perfectly in general. Why I would get that exception? And under what scenario?

EDIT: 
the exception occurs at this line. The tag in xml is correct and I just got this crashed for few times.
BTW, I didn't find any useful information in my code or log output.

```
mInputView = (MyView) mRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.myview);
```

Comment: can you show us the code where exception occurs ?

Comment: can you add your code and error

Comment: post logcat to us and try clean your project too

Comment: try to clean project and run.... it should work if code is right

Comment: Are you working with different class loaders?

Comment: @Henry, I have no idea. This is an exception log sent from device on users hand to our server.